# What is the potential impact of security risks associated specifically with 3D printers or their hosts?

Tags: risk-management, risk, printers

Recently a bunch of Anycubic 3D printers have been hacked as reported in an article from  [bleedingcomputer.com](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/anycubic-3d-printers-hacked-worldwide-to-expose-security-flaw/).

> According to a wave of online reports from Anycubic customers, someone hacked their 3D printers to warn that the devices are exposed to attacks.

> According to the same text file, 2,934,635 devices downloaded this warning message via the vulnerable API.

> [image: hacked_machine_readme.gcode]

The impact in this case seems limited to only a warning using a text file that was placed on the printer. However, I can imagine a scenario where (through an intermediate host such as OctoPrint) the printer firmware can be reflashed (some OctoPlugin for example allows for remote flashing). The firmware could for form a real physical danger, for example when thermal runaway protection or heat limits are removed, or false values are reported to the printer LCD.

My question is, what specific vulnerabilities or risks are associates with 3D printers or 3D printer hosts and what potential impact does it have?

Comment: I'm not sure about the question. If you are asking how malicious firmware could affect the intended functionality of a 3rd printer -  an intentionally malfunctioning printer might be a safety problem, like through overheating etc. But safety is not information security, i.e. off-topic. If you are asking how a compromised IoT device (which the printer is) could affect its environment (attacks inside LAN or to internet) - that's not different to any other compromised IoT device (printer, SmartTV, ...).

Comment: "What's the security risk of a compromised device on a network?" -- is a well- discussed topic. Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: I rephrased. I'm more interested in the impact, however apart from the standard 'breached network-device' I'm more interested in the specific risks and impacts associated with network connected 3D printers or 3D printer hosts such as OctoPi.

Comment: So, as we said, just as there is for any other device. Physical safety hazards are outside of the infosec scope and the risk analysis of that will depend entirely on the physical capabilities of the machine. So, I'm not sure there is a unique answer possible here.

Comment: You're right. I will request a migration to 3D printing Stack Exchange.